# Editing div code added by Jquery Append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive successfully appended a html file to my website containing only the menu and title image.
I wanted every web page on my website to have the same menu , title and structure.
Everything works fine but I have no idea how to edit a div that I added using append function (jquery).

for example: lets say that I appeneded a file named "include.html" and that file contains a div named "website". is there any way I can add code/content to that DIV after appending it ?

I need access to the DIVS appended by the APPEND function in order to add unique texts/information for each page..

here is some code:

A sample page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyles.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='menu2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='menu_load.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>loadContent(); 
    $(document).on('mouseenter', "#menulist", function() {
          mainmenu();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here's the menu2.js code:

```
function mainmenu() {
     $(" #menulist li").hover(function() {
         $(this).find('ul:first').css({
              visibility: "visible",
              display: "none"}).show(300);
         },function() {
              $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
     });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     mainmenu();
});
```

here's the menu_load.js code:

```
function loadContent() {
     $("body").append($("<div id='index'>").load("include.html"));
}
```

The reason Im trying to do that is that I want to add unique information on the main DIV containing the website.. If theres a better way doing that (without JQUERY append) i would love to know..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) .. to append content inside `div` with id `website`.. after the include.html is appended on load callback function

> callback function: If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

try this

```
function loadContent()
{
  $("body").append($("<div id='index'>").load("include.html", function() {
       $("#website").text("HELLO"); // OR $("website").html("HELLO");
  });
}
```

Comment: Same proble, page turns blank now. what could be the reason?

Comment: `$("#website").text("HELLO");` did u try this in callback function this should work ..try it.. let me know if any prob....

Comment: ok that means you have some error in javascript code.... please check your firebug console... for error.. and let me know what is the error....ok

Comment: ok.. if you are using firefox... download this addons http://getfirebug.com/.... very helpful for javascript debug for developers... you can go through the documents in the site...

Comment: Ok.. done. it seems to get in infinite loop when executing the command: loadContent(); (function call ofcourse)

Comment: :)....welcome.. have fun coding.. :).... start using firebug.... killer tools for developers especially for javascript debugs .. :)....

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Find the id (or some other jquery way of finding that div), and just call a function on the load:

```
function loadContent() {
  $("body").append($("<div id='index'></div>").load("include.html", {}, function() {
    $("#div_id").html(new_content);
  });
}
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Tried, the page turns blank now.. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function to the `load(...)` call in jQuery. So, you could do something like this:

```
$("body").append($("<div id='index'>").load("include.html", function () {
    $(this).append("<div>your html content</div>");
}));
```

This will insert the text `your html content` to the end of the div. Obviously, you could use something other than append if you wanted it to be somewhere else.